# Joomla 2.5 - "My profile" button disappeared after upgrading

Tags: joomla

I upgraded my Joomla! from 1.7 to 2.5 and have the problem, that the "My profile" button is not shown when a user has successfully logged-in. It appeared in 1.7 after a user has logged-in. 
Can someone give me a hint please?

Thanks,

enne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading, some code changes in the login-module, which I just overwrote with the code from v1.7.